# How to setup FrameTicks for TradingChart

Tags: ticks, finance, charts

I'm trying to setup FrameTicks for TradingChart, but it dosn't work.

```
(*take data*)
data = FinancialData["NASDAQ:AAPL", "OHLCV", {{2017, 1, 1}, {2017, 4, 16}}];

(*def. of ticks*)
maxh = Max[#[[2]]&/@Last/@data];
minl = Min[#[[3]]&/@Last/@data];
lstYTicks = Table[i,{i,minl,maxh,(maxh-minl)/6}];

(*draw chart*)
TradingChart[data,
 Frame -> True,
 FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, lstYTicks}, {Automatic, Automatic}},
 GridLines -> {Automatic, lstYTicks},
 GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Gray, Dotted],
 ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

It seems that **FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, lstYTicks}, {Automatic, Automatic}}** option pattern is invalid here. How to solve this case. Thanks!

Comment: Assumed GridLines and Ticks are set up as the trading reference lines of the share prices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main fault is not operating correct on TimeSeries!

```
(*def.of ticks*)
maxh = Max[# & /@ data["Values"][[All, 2]]][[1]]
minl = Min[# & /@ data["Values"][[All, 2]]][[1]]
lstYTicks = Table[i, {i, minl, maxh, (maxh - minl)/6}]

*draw chart*)
TradingChart[data, Frame -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {lstYTicks, Automatic}}, 
 ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

works the intended manner in V12.0.0.